# Método RegisterBundles da Classe BundleConfig sem caminhos absolutos ou URIs fixas

Tags: c#, sonarqube

Se eu estou aqui é porque não consegui achar até o momento algo exato ou que satisfaça meu problema. Deixe-me explicar:

Estou usando o **SONARQUBE** ou apenas **SONAR** para avaliação do código, detecção de erros, boas praticas, etc no meu projeto de trabalho.

E ele (SONAR) acusou algumas inconsistências algo como boa pratica de segurança na classe BundleConfig.cs

**Como assim?**

Bem, a classe `BundleConfig.cs` vem com o método `RegisterBundles()` já configurado por *default* conforme o próprio Visual Studio cria, correto?

[image: Parte do Código]

Porém, o SONAR, pede que eu **refatore meu código para não usar caminhos absolutos ou URIs fixas**, e ele critica o trecho de código da imagem acima como:

[image: Crítica do SONAR]

Tentei fazer algo semelhante a:

1. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14797063/hard-coding-a-relative-path-in-c-sharp
2. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14697074/asp-net-mvc-4-0-bundles-with-multiple-absolute-urls-for-styles
3. http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301862
4. E outras comunidades que consultei, mas todos as ideias de soluções apresentam erros, não funcionam dentro da classe ou não serviram para o proposito que preciso aplicar na `BundleConfig.cs`

Então, só criei essa dúvida porque realmente esgotei todo meu hype de conhecimento.

Se alguém tiver alguma sugestão ou ideia de como eu possa resolver será bem-vinda.

Sem mais, obrigado pela atenção.

Comment: Palpite, acho que não tem muito o que fazer nesse caso além de reconhecer essas críticas como um falso positivo. E também não valeria mudar o seu "Bundler" para um grunt ou gulp apenas para a análise do sonar.

Comment: @LeandroAngelo compartilho da mesma ideia e acredito que tenha razão (votei como comentário útil). Pois foi o que eu estava pensando, mas fiz o _post_ com a pergunta para ter uma segunda opinião, pois os analistas vão questionar e preciso estar embasado.